# Gremlin get vertices where there exists a bidirectional edge connecting them

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

Mine is a simple social network scenario people make friends and post pictures and those pictures should be visible to people only if there exists a 2 way relation ship between them

```
g.addV("user").property("name","X").as('x').
  addV("user").property("name","Y").as('y').
  addV("post").property("name","p1").as('p1').
  addE("posts").from("x").to("p1").
  addE("friend").from("x").to("y").iterate()
```

right now there exists an only one-way relationship between X and Y. Y should only see the posts of X only if there exists bidirectional relations ship  i.e

```
g.addE("friend").from(V().has("name","Y")).to(V().has("name","X")).iterate()
```

now there is both way edge of the same type between X and Y so both can view each other posts.

my code to get posts of all friends of Y but not working

```
g.V("name","Y").both("friend").out("posts").toList().next();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the more direct way to write this is with:

```
g.V().has("name","Y").as('y').
  out('friend').
  where(__.in('friend').as('y')).
  out('posts').values('name')
```

So, find "Y" and label that step as "y", then traverse to friends, filter out any "friend" vertices who don't match back to "y" using `where()` then for those matches get the posts.

```
gremlin> g.addV("user").property("name","X").as('x').
......1>   addV("user").property("name","Y").as('y').
......2>   addV("post").property("name","p1").as('p1').
......3>   addE("posts").from("x").to("p1").
......4>   addE("friend").from("x").to("y").iterate()
gremlin> g.V().has("name","Y").as('y').
......1>   out('friend').
......2>   where(__.in('friend').as('y')).
......3>   out('posts').values('name')
gremlin> g.addE("friend").from(V().has("name","Y")).to(V().has("name","X")).iterate()
gremlin> g.V().has("name","Y").as('y').
......1>   out('friend').
......2>   where(__.in('friend').as('y')).
......3>   out('posts').values('name')
==>p1
```

Comment: well, you changed the working `where()` clause to something that is not valid.if you change it back to what I had, the rest will work. also, there is no need to label `out('posts')` or to `select()` it in the second `by()` modulator...`project()` already has reference to it. just include an empty `by()` and it will work as you are hoping

Comment: sorry...perhaps you did not follow what I wrote, change the contents of the `where()` step back to what I had. That does not affect your ability to get the user data. in other words, this: `__.in('friend').is(eq('y'))` is wrong and should be what I had in `__.in('friend').as('y')`. you can choose to make the other suggestions i made in my previous comment or not...either way, the traversal should return the same data form in `project()`

Comment: whoa...sorry @mmr25 looks like i had some bad cut/paste code in my example.not sure how that happened.  i see why you tried what you tried. hopefully it's more clear now that my post was edited